# ggplot and R: Issue with barplot and the width of the bars when certain x values are missing

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a certain data set that displays the sales revenue for two companies during 4 years.

```
year <- c(2009, 2011, 2012, 2009,2010, 2012)
name <- c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B')
sales <- c(500, 1000, 2000, 1500, 1000, 500)
df.t <- data.frame(year, name, sales)
```

Output:

```
> year name sales
> 2009    A    500
> 2011    A   1000
> 2012    A   2000
> 2009    B   1500
> 2010    B   1000
> 2012    B    500
```

Note that for company A there is no sales number for the year 2010 (there were no sales in that year) and for company B there is no sales number in the year 2011.

I would like to create a nice bar chart showing these numbers.

```
ggplot(data=df.t, aes(x=year, y=sales, fill=name)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")
```

However, this creates a bar chart where the bars for the year 2010 and 2011 do not have the same width than for the other years. 
[image]

I would like to have a bar chart even for the years with no sales. That barchart would have a height of 0.

How can I do this without changing the data and adding zeros?

Comment: It'd be great if you fixed this question so that the names in your data frame creation (`y`,`n`, `z`) matched the names of the vectors (`year` `name` `sales`) and matched the column names in the plot (which includes `return`).

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I've fixed it. Names in the data frame should match name of vectors now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I would like to have a bar chart even for the years with no sales. That barchart would have a height of 0. How can I do this without changing the data and adding zeros?

It's generally difficult to make `ggplot` plot data that's not there. The `facet` option in @Thomas K's answer works because `x` and `y` scales by default are the same in every facet, regardless of data presence/absence. However, I think that adding zeros is the best way and isn't as hard as you think. Just add the zeros. `tidyr::complete` makes it very easy.

```
library(tidyr)
ggplot(complete(df.t, year, name, fill = list(sales = 0)),
       aes(x=year, y=sales, fill=name)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")
```

[image]

Note: this assumes that your data is this:

```
year <- c(2009, 2011, 2012, 2009,2010, 2012)
name <- c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B')
sales <- c(500, 1000, 2000, 1500, 1000, 500)
df.t <- data.frame(year, name, sales)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `facet_grid`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

year <- c(2009, 2011, 2012, 2009,2010, 2012)
name <- c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B')
sales <- c(500, 1000, 2000, 1500, 1000, 500)
df.t <- data.frame(year, name, sales)

ggplot(df.t, aes(name, sales, fill = name)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", show.legend = F) +
  facet_grid(. ~ year) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: geom_bar(stat = "identity", **show.legend = F**) does not work for me to remove the legend. Had to use + guides(fill=FALSE) instead

Comment: @AllYouCanEat86 I was using the dev-version. `guides(fill=F)` will be deprecated in the next release of `ggplot2`. To install the dev-version you can run `install.packages("devtools"); devtools::install_github("hadley/ggplot2")`